# Deleting files with multiprocessing in python

Tags: multiprocessing, python-3.5

I am using the following code to delete large number of files in python:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def deleteFiles(loc):
    def Fn_deleteFiles(inp):
        [fn, loc] = [inp['fn'], inp['loc']]
        os.remove(os.path.join(loc, fn))

    p = Pool(5)
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(loc):
        if len(files) > 0:
            inpData = [{'fn':x, 'loc':loc} for x in files]
            p.map(Fn_deleteFiles, inpData)
    p.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loc = r'C:\myDriveWithFilesToDelete'
    deleteFiles(loc)
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'deleteFiles.<locals>.Fn_deleteFiles'
```

Comment: General observation: I think `multiprocessing.Pool` spawns new a whole new Python process for every item in the list. Maybe using a `ThreadPool` is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a function, inside of a function.

The function `Fn_deleteFiles(inp)`, is defined inside of `deleteFiles(loc)`.

*This means that `Fn_deleteFiles(inp)` is _only_ made when `deleteFiles(loc)` is run.*

The problem is that, internally, `multiprocessing.pool.Pool()` calls the `pickle` library to transfer function objects from this python process, to the one new python function that is being spawned.

However, **`pickle` will fail to *stringify* a function, if it can not locate the functions origin.**

Here is a demo that demonstrates a similar error.

```
import pickle
def foo():
    def bar():
        return "Hello"
    return bar

bar = foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = pickle.dumps(bar)
```

Will cause the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../stacktest.py", line 10, in <module>
    s = pickle.dumps(bar)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'foo.<locals>.bar'
```

So to fix this error, you can either use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` instead, as it does not pickle.

```
import os
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
def deleteFiles(loc):
    def Fn_deleteFiles(inp):
        [fn, loc] = [inp['fn'], inp['loc']]
        os.remove(os.path.join(loc, fn))
    p = Pool(5)
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(loc):
        if len(files) > 0:
            inpData = [{'fn':x, 'loc':loc} for x in files]
            p.map(Fn_deleteFiles, inpData)
    p.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loc = 'DriveWithFilesToDelete'
    deleteFiles(loc)
```

Alternatively, you can define the `Fn_deleteFiles(inp)` outside of `deleteFiles(loc)` to fix this issue.

***WARNING*** For reasons I don't understand, this answer will hang inside of the idle interpreter.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def Fn_deleteFiles(inp):
    print("Delete", inp)
    [fn, loc] = [inp['fn'], inp['loc']]
    os.remove(os.path.join(loc, fn))

def deleteFiles(loc):
    p = Pool(5)
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(loc):
        if len(files) > 0:
            inpData = [{'fn':x, 'loc':loc} for x in files]
            p.map(Fn_deleteFiles, inpData)
    p.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loc = 'DriveWithFilesToDelete'
    deleteFiles(loc)
```